# How hard is it to change industries as a software engineer?

Tags: software-industry, career-development

I'm considering accepting a software engineering offer at a large defence company. I'm not a software engineer and don't know much about software engineering, however I can code in Matlab and python for maths and statistics related problems.

I like the sound of being a software engineer and would be more than willing to learn what I need to. What I'm unsure about is:

- how hard is to change industries as a software engineer? (I can't see myself in defence for too long)
- are there too many software engineers? Is the market too saturated
- is it a good time to be starting a software engineering career given the recent mass lay-offs at tech companies?

Comment: Can't really say much about the future oriented questions, but when I've had to change industries in the past it wasn't a problem. Whether it's a financial website or a commerce site or a desktop app or service it's always the same work. Just with different business requirements.

Comment: I guess you are talking about the USA? Or do you want a global perspective?

Comment: @nvoigt I'm based in the UK so trying to understand what the software engineering space is like here

Comment: Changing industries is not the real issue. The real issue is how vastly different styles of programming exist in different companies. Defense computing is very different from a scrappy startup company computing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how hard is to change industries as a software engineer? (I can't see myself in defence for too long)

It's not particularly difficult to change industries as a software eng. in the UK unless you're working exclusively (or at the very least *extensively*) with industry-specific tech stacks or methodologies.

I've worked in six different industry sectors - and I've only had two jobs that shared a sector. Some have very easily transferred skills between them - there's only so many different ways you can run an e-commerce business for example and the core is the same whether you're selling Widgets or Thingamabobs.

Domain knowledge can be very valuable in certain sectors - particularly where it's knowledge that doesn't correspond well to any others. Being able to short-cut the typical *"here's how our industry works"* crash course can make you an attractive candidate. Additionally certain industries come with bonuses in the form of things like various security clearances which can be incredibly valuable in all sorts of business you wouldn't necessarily expect. Mine's lapsed now but you wouldn't *believe* the diversity and sheer quantity of businesses clamouring for cleared personnel, often at quite lucrative rates!

> are there too many software engineers? Is the market too saturated

This is going to vary around the country, but the market seems reasonably healthy of late, there's a reasonably high demand and while there's probably a fair amount more people in the area than there were say, 20 years ago there's been quite a growth in companies looking to hire. I think the fact that you've got an offer *already*, despite relative inexperience in the field speaks volumes.

> is it a good time to be starting a software engineering career given the recent mass lay-offs at tech companies?

There's been some big headlines about some of the larger tech companies laying off workers certainly - and that's going to make things a little harder as you'd potentially be competing with *some*  of these newly-redundant staff who already have more skills and experience than a new entrant - but it's perhaps not as bad you'd think because they won't really be looking for entry-level/junior roles. As for the future - there's no guarantees, no crystal ball, nothing that can really tell you for sure what the state of the field is going to be in 10 years, or even in 5 years really. *But the same is true for many career paths*, so try not to get too hung up on it.

Comment: Great points, appreciate your thoughts. One thing I forgot to mention, it seems like there's so much you need to know in software engineering and feels like you need to constantly keep learning. My social media feeds are filled with people discussing/arguing about things like React, node, JS, etc. How do software engineers keep up with it all as they progress? And how do you know what's important to invest time into learning about?

Comment: @chewwy We don't know. We take a guess and try something. There are many, many new technologies that come along and are heavily promoted for a while and then, slip into obscurity. The best thing is to learn how to learn quickly.

Answer (score -1):

It is best to stick to an industry because domain knowledge matters.  Domain knowledge lets you solve problems without code.

That said, coders change industries all the time. You would focus on the type of coding knowledge and not domain knowledge.  Like "User Experience expertise."

If your defense job comes with a security clearance, this is almost a guaranteed job for life because the cost of entry is very high and these jobs generally cannot be outsourced.